# Saving image from gallery in room database is not working

Tags: java, android, roomdb

I am currently developing an app in Android Studio (in Java) that can save some drawings and count the number of drawings per month you did.

I am using Room database and for the moment I only have one entity which is Drawing. It contains a title (string), a date (string) and an image (byte[]).

I have a form to add a drawing and I load an image from the gallery.
When I add a drawing with no image (only date and title) it works, but when I add the image it does not save the drawing anymore.

I think it is the way I am getting the image that is making my code crashes.

I don't really know what to do, is there anyone who has an idea to fix the problem ?

```
package com.example.sketchhub.views;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.sketchhub.R;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class AddDrawing extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText drawingTitleInput, drawingDateInput;
    private ImageView drawingImageInput;
    private Button saveBtn, addImgBtn;

    public static final String EXTRA_ID = "com.gtappdevelopers.gfgroomdatabase.EXTRA_ID";
    public static final String EXTRA_TITLE = "com.gtappdevelopers.gfgroomdatabase.EXTRA_TITLE";
    public static final String EXTRA_DATE = "com.gtappdevelopers.gfgroomdatabase.EXTRA_DATE";
    public static final String EXTRA_IMAGE = "com.gtappdevelopers.gfgroomdatabase.EXTRA_IMAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_drawing);

        // get inputs
        drawingTitleInput = findViewById(R.id.addDrawing_titleInput);
        drawingDateInput = findViewById(R.id.addDrawing_dateInput);
        drawingImageInput = findViewById(R.id.addDrawing_imgView);

        // get save button
        saveBtn = findViewById(R.id.addDrawing_btnSaveDrawing);
        addImgBtn = findViewById(R.id.addDrawing_btnAddImage);

        // set date
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String date = dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        drawingDateInput.setText(date);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_ID)) {
            drawingTitleInput.setText(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TITLE));
            drawingDateInput.setText(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_DATE));
            byte[] imageByteArray = intent.getByteArrayExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE);
            if (imageByteArray != null) {
                Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByteArray, 0, imageByteArray.length);
                drawingImageInput.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            }
        }

        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String drawingTitle = drawingTitleInput.getText().toString();
                String drawingDate = drawingDateInput.getText().toString();


                byte[] imageByteArray = null;

                // Check if there is an image in the ImageView
                if (drawingImageInput.getDrawable() instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                    // If an image is selected, convert it to byte array
                    Bitmap imageBitmap = getBitmapFromImageView(drawingImageInput);
                    imageByteArray = getBytesFromBitmap(imageBitmap);
                } else {
                    // If no image is selected, set imageByteArray to null
                    imageByteArray = null;
                }

                
                if (drawingDate.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddDrawing.this, "Please enter valid drawing details.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (drawingTitle.isEmpty()) {
                    drawingTitle = "No Title";
                }

                saveDrawing(drawingTitle, drawingDate, imageByteArray);
            }
        });

        addImgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
            }
        });
    }

    private void saveDrawing(String drawingTitle, String drawingDate, byte[] imageByteArray) {
        Intent data = new Intent();

        data.putExtra(EXTRA_TITLE, drawingTitle);
        data.putExtra(EXTRA_DATE, drawingDate);

        if (imageByteArray != null) {
            data.putExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE, imageByteArray);
        }

        int id = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_ID, -1);
        if (id != -1) {
            data.putExtra(EXTRA_ID, id);
        }

        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Drawing has been saved to Room Database. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Finish the current activity
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 3 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                drawingImageInput.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromImageView(ImageView imageView) {
        Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();

        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            // If the ImageView has a BitmapDrawable, extract the Bitmap
            return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        } else {
            // If the ImageView doesn't have a BitmapDrawable, try to create a Bitmap from the Drawable
            int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

            if (width <= 0 || height <= 0) {
                return null;
            }

            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            drawable.draw(canvas);

            return bitmap;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to debug the code.

When I get the drawable, it actually returns an empty string.
This is why I think this is the problem.